# while running android application..it always says app has stopped

Tags: android

only this part of code causes app has stopped..but if i remove this code everything is working fine...what shall i do?

```
 listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
final String[] values= new String[]{"starter","juices","roties"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.menu_fragment,R.id.listTextView,values);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if(pos==0){
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(view.getContext(),StarterActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
        }
        if(pos==1){
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(view.getContext(),JuicesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,1);
        }
        if(pos==2){
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(view.getContext(),StarterActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,2);
        }
    }
});
```

In menu_fragment.xml

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
<TextView android:id="@+id/listTextView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

i hv created one package inside my com.events named as mFragments and in that package i have created java class named MenuFragment

```
    public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and in activity_starter.xml and activity_juices.xml ...simply there is textview whose text is starter and juices ...it should display accordingly

In short i did this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOVwg3zitwg&t=390s

and now in same project i wanna do this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kUBcbUMDKE&t=506s

but its not working..it always shows app has stopped error.. i took menufragment n in that i wnna display expandable listview which will show my hotel's menus.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: android monitor..logcat is blank...it is not showing any error..or any exception

Comment: post the complete activity code and layouts you used and make your you have manifest containing corresponding activities

Comment: ok i will post it :) thank u

Comment: can u plz giv me ur email id? I will send u whole project

Comment: just post the code of required java files and XML files

Comment: Pls, add of code from the file to the post.

Comment: In menu_fragment.xml

Comment: In menu_fragment.xml               <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: i hv created one package inside my com.events and in that package i have created java class named MenuFragment  which extends                       Fragment class..in that i wrote
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment,container,false);
        return rootView;

Comment: and in activity_starter.xml and activity_juices.xml ...simply there is textview whose text is starter and juices ...it should display accordingly

Comment: please don't flood the comments section with code , you can use edit option to modify your question and details with proper formatting and remove unwanted comments

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run activity from view.getContext()

Use Fragment or Activity context

Comment: m new to android :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `view.getContext()` replace it with `MainActivity.this` or whatever your class name is (from which you are calling startActivity() method).

Comment: i put MenuFragment.this ...but its showing me an error

Comment: is not an enclosing class